# Feedback on Latin to English Translation

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, sentence-translation

I am currently learning Latin and is a beginner. However, I am unsure of my answers and is looking for help to proofread and provide suggestions for improvement. Would appreciate all feedback I receive. Thank you.

1. Therefore, I choose to work in the food and beverage industry because I can learn many skills from the cook. *Igitur eligo operam in pabulo et pota industria quod possum disco multas sollertias ex coqua.*
2. I learned to use the knife to slice raw fish and prepare special and delicious desserts. *Dicobam adhibeo cultum seco crudo pisco et paro peculiaram et delicatam secundam.*
3. I learned to make saffron salmon. *Dicobam facio croceum salmum.* [Salmon > Salmo however how should it be translated if it is a direct object/acc.)
4. For I am happy, I will not complain of the long work hours and tough job. *Enim sum fortunatus, ero non queror longam operam horas et tenax officio.*

Answer (score 4):

Professional Latin tutor to the rescue:

For #1: "to work" is an infinitive verb, and "food and beverage" would be in the genitive (think "the industry of food and beverage"). Also, when there is a form of "possum," the verb that denotes what is abled is also in the infinitive. With respect to diction, I think *cibus, cibi* would better for food and *operor* (careful, this is a deponent verb). Further, verbs tend to go last in a clause. Therefore:

> 1. *Igitur (Ideo), in industriā cibī potūsque operārī eligō (optō), quod multās pertiās ē coquō/ā* [depending on gender of the cook] *discere possum.* 
>    (words in parentheses are other suggested words which might better fit)

For #2: Most of the verbs aside from "learned" are either in the infinitive or in the subjunctive mood. Moreover, "dicobam" is not a word (at least in this context). Finally, you need to expand your sentences first "I learned how to..."

therefore:

> 2. *(Quōmodō) cultrō uti ut piscem crudum secem et bellaria (secundās) eximia(-ās) deliciosa(-ās-)que parem discebām (didicī).*
>     (the (-ās) is used in place of the "-a" ending if the (*secundās*) is used. (*Didicī*) is the perfect tense.)

For #3: Salmon = *esicia. There is an adjective form of Saffron.

Therefore:

> 3. *Esiciam croceam facere discebam (didicī)*.

For #4: Happy=*felix*, or *laetus*, and always use the future tense of the verb itself, not the verb "to be."

therefore

> 4. *Nam felix (laetus) sum; dē longīs horīs operae et officiō difficillī non querebor.*

Comment: Sorry, it took me several days to complete; there was a lot here.